# Angular SSR with wildfly

Tags: angular, wildfly, server-side-rendering

A search a solution Server side rendering with angular on wildfly. But I don't want to use other server, like nodejs.

Is any reliable solution? Or the best way the Angular universal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to leverage on NodeJS, and your angular app only has static content, then you can use prerendering.

After adding @nguniversal to your project, you get a new command in your root package.json

```
"prerender": "ng run prerendering-demo:prerender"
```

Running this command will produce only html, css and javascript files. javascript navigation is still enabled. So after running

```
npm run prerender
```

You can simply upload the output in the `dist/[project name]/browser` folder to a simple webserver to host your app. I tested this with the following commands

```
ng new prerendering-demo --style=scss --routing --strict
cd prerendering-demo
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine

cd src/app
ng g module --routing pages
cd pages
ng g module home --module pages --route /
ng g module about --module pages --route about
ng g module contact --module pages --route contact
# just correct the / for the homepage in the pages-routing.module.ts

npm run prerender
npm install --global http-server
cd ../../dist/prerendering-demo/browser
http-server
# Visit http://127.0.0.1:8081
```